# Can I set Chrome to call my local anti-virus software to scan each downloaded file?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

All I want is to have Chrome execute the anti-virus software I set, passing the file path, after it has download each file.

Note, I'm not taking about any Chrome built-in security nor cloud scanning.

Comment: Typically security products use the IOfficeAntivirus to be able to scan the file at download. Chrome supports this, Firefox for example does not.  They may also have scanned the file before it even hits the browser as part of some web protection feature.  The real-time scanning will also typically scan the file has it is written to disk and then again as it's executed.  What security product do you have installed?

Comment: @HelpingHand, MS Security Essentials on Win 7 ;)